# Raspberry Pi did not autoconnect to ethernet

Tags: boot, ethernet, headless, ethernet-port

So I do not have a monitor. I just put the raspbian image onto the microsd card using the instructions from https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md. When I put the microsd card in the raspberry pi B model 1 and boot it up, the only led lit is the red one (the green flashed once, I think). The ethernet port isn't flashing at all.

Shouldn't it autoconnect to ethernet and then provide ssh?

Comment: Possibly an issue with your SD card. Try to reflash a clean Raspbian or NOOBS and try again. Make sure to check the md5 to be sure it's a complete, valid image.

Comment: Depends on what distribution you have and how recent it is but I don't think SSH is active at boot. Maybe the most recent Raspbian's do enable SSH by default but chances are you need a HDMI-enabled monitor to run raspi-config and enable SSH on boot. Someone might need to confirm.

Comment: "The ethernet port is flashing at all." That's bit of ambiguous sentence as it looks like you forgot the word "not". Did you mean "not at all" or (sth like) "all the time" ?

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas Sorry. Typo.

Comment: @HeatherBrown They only give a hash for the zipped file. I can't verify it after is on the microsd card.

Comment: It very much sounds like there is something wrong with the sd card. The red led should be on, the green led should be flickering from time to time and surely during bootup. Furthermore the ethernet port should be flasing regularly and be more on than off. Can you provide the command that you used to put it on the sd card? And do you have another sd card with which you can test it with?

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas I used this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md. Maybe I can try it with another card.

Comment: @PyRulez that is a proper procedure. You could try the steps at the end to verify if was written correctly, but (imo) that is 'overkill'.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really broad and instead of a plain a precise answer, this should be a series of questions. Not enough information to give you just -one- answer. Let's try.

Unless your previously configured your **RPI O/S**, it is not trivial to work without a monitor, also, will be convenient to have a *UART* to *USB* cable plugged to *GPIO* 6/8/10 and use Putty to talk through the 'console', however, not having them is not the end.

You did not mention your **RPI** model, nor the O/S your are trying to use, I must add that you can't start with the default **NOOBS** distribution: you will need interaction (and a monitor)

Now, the following is the most basic and generic setting for a headless unit, also works with Zero:

1. Download the latest **Wheezy** or **Jessie** image from the ***Raspberry PI*** site
2. Extract the image from the zip file
3. Use **win32DiskImager** to create a new SD card
4. Install the memory card on the device
5. Connect your *Ethernet* cable.
6. Connect the power micro *USB*.

You will need to find the *DHCP* assigned IP address then fire your *Putty* SSH connection.

Comment: If you had read the comments on his question, you could've easily concluded that he did do step 1-6, but **then** things went wrong ...

Comment: Deaderik: the place to modify the _question_ is on the _question_, edit if you need to add more information; _answers_ are _answer_  to the main _question_ not to comments.When a question match your need, you don't read every comment, just look for a qualified answer.